# which node is motion planner in moveit?

Tags: ros, rviz, moveit, action, rqt-graph

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**BACKGROUND**

This passage from book MASTER ROS FOR ROBOTICS PROGRAMMING, which explains **how motion planner works in moveit** raises my question:

> **MoveIt! can talk to the motion
> planners through the plugin interface**.
> We can use any motion planner by
> simply changing the plugin. This
> method is highly extensible so we can
> try our own custom motion planners
> using this interface. **The move_group
> node talks to the motion planner
> plugin via the ROS action/services.**
> The default planner for the move_group
> node is OMPL
> (http://ompl.kavrakilab.org/)

> **To start motion planning, we should
> send a motion planning request to the
> motion planner** which specified our
> planning requirements. The planning
> requirement may be setting a new **goal**
> pose of the end-effector, for example,
> for a **pick and place** operation.
>
> We can set additional kinematic
> constraints for the motion planners.
> Given next are some inbuilt
> constraints in MoveIt!:

> ......

> Using these constraints, we can
> **send a motion planning request** and the
> **planner will generate a suitable
> trajectory** according to the request.
> **The move_group node will generate the
> suitable trajectory from the motion
> planner which obeys all the
> constraints.** This can be sent to robot
> joint trajectory controllers

**QUESTION1:**

I wonder **which node is motion planner in moveit**?

Could u **explain the above passage using the image below**?

**QUESTION2:**

As the **figure shown below**, while there are nodes of **action_topics** in the namespace of **place and pickup** respectively, there is also a node of **action_topics** in the namespace of **move_group**, which **seems redundant to me**, there must be something I misunderstand.

**QUESTION3:**

What's more, **they form a loop in combination with move_group and rviz**, I do not quite understand how things work

Here is the **rqt_graph** for **moveit_config demo.launch**

[image: image description]

**EDIT1**

Quoted from [official moveit concept introduction](http://moveit.ros.org/documentation/concepts/)

> move_group is structured to be easily extensible - individual capabilities like **pick and place**, kinematics, **motion
> planning** are actually implemented as **separate plugins** with a common base class. **The plugins are configurable
> using ROS through a set of ROS yaml parameters and through the use of the ROS pluginlib library**. Most users will
> not have to configure move_group plugins since they come **automatically configured in the launch files generated
> by the MoveIt! Setup Assistant.**

**QUESTION4**

From above, I realize that the **plugins are configured by pluginlib and yaml parameters, instead of nodes**, so obviously there is **no node in rqt_graph for motion planner**, right?

**QUESTION5**

What's more, **motion planner** is **part of the move_group node**?

**QUESTION6**

So-called **motion planning request**, mentioned in many tutorials, is offered by **rviz gui** or **user's code**, right?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/252075/which-node-is-motion-planner-in-moveit?/) by [shawnysh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28421/shawnysh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 339 on 2017-01-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Question 1: Obsolete

Question 2: These are not redundant. Pickup and Place are actions that need a ROS action interface (i.e. "action_topics"), move_group is a ROS node, but the name is **also** used for an action that accepts PlanningRequests. There is a Ticket to change the name of one of them [here](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/issues/95).

Question 3: That's not a question. ROS nodes are not restricted to loop-less communication graphs.

Question 4: Yes

Question 5: Well, it's a couple of C++ classes that are provided in the move_group node, but you could also use the classes in your own code (although you should probably to start with using the move_group node if you're new to MoveIt.

Question 6: Yes. The [MoveGroupInterface C++ class](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/moveit_ros_planning_interface/html/classmoveit_1_1planning__interface_1_1MoveGroupInterface.html) can be used to construct them more easily and send them via the `move` and `plan` methods.

---

Originally posted by [v4hn](https://answers.ros.org/users/4809/v4hn/) with karma: 2950 on 2017-01-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [shawnysh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28421/shawnysh/) on 2017-01-16**:
Thanks a lot for your reply. It really helps!!!